# No mesh data to join

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

I am trying to join this rig with this mesh and no luck.

What am I doing wrong? All I get is an error message that says no mesh data to join even though I can clearly see the mesh.
still having an issue the file can be found here.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ThmLzTIZvY4pbW_cmrk5B5CqjYMlXXvC

[image]

Comment: Typically when we see a picture of an armature and a mesh, the reader thinks, the armature will control the mesh ... via mesh with armature [parent] with automatic weights.  Then a leg bone will rotate the leg part of the mesh.  Are you binding a mesh to an armature?  When I hear the word [join] in Blender,  I think of two meshes being joined.  Are you clear about those two different concepts?

Comment: If you try to join mesh with armature that's exactly what the message you'll see. Both objects to be joined need to be mesh objects. In case of armature and rigging mesh object is parented to armature instead.

Comment: Here is a tutorial. https://youtu.be/GvG39bGEsKI

Comment: If your goal is to bind a mesh to an armature you probably want to change the title of your question.  Example .... How do I bind a mesh to an armature?

Comment: The armature is not joined to a mesh, they are different kinds of objects, incompatible kinds of data. Armatures are **parented** to objets so that they can control deformations

Comment: yes I am trying to join the mesh to the armature as to be able to move the limbs of the animal, currently my rig is live so to speak (blue) but I can not bind it to the mesh, so is control P with auto weights the proper command for this op ? will check out the tutorial